# I Want to sync my gmail account with GMAIL API but with option one month ago or two month ago

Tags: node.js, api, gmail, gmail-api

I Want to sync my gmail account with GMAIL API but with option one month ago or two month ago, how can i use the query search ?
this is my code

```
    **function getMails(client, userId, maxResults){
var query = "before:2020-10-12"
      const service = google.gmail('v1')
      const opts = {
        auth: client,
        userId
      }
      if(maxResults!='') opts.maxResults = maxResults
      if (query) {
        opts.q = query
      }
      console.log(opts)
      service.users.messages.list(opts, getApiResponseHandler(resolve, reject))
}**
```

should i change the query ?

Comment: Your query is correct. Is your question about how to dynamically set the date to "one month ago" instead of hardcoding it to "before:2020-10-12"? Or do you want to query instead for messages that are newer than 1 month?

Comment: @ziganotschka, for that one i handled the problem, so from the API is only use one_month_ago, two_month_ago, three_month_ago, this is my first time to use GMAIL API, so i didn't know my query was right, but how about fetching gmail List start from now? can i just put q = "after:2020-10-22" ? because i use that query, but the system still fetching old mails (before 2020-10-22)

Comment: Yes, it should be correct. Doublecheck your results with the Gmail UI and the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list)